# Why does the order of eigenvectors matter when changing a matrix to a different basis?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, quantum-mechanics

I'm solving a basic problem in quantum mechanics to change the matrix A into a representation in the basis consisting of eigenvectors of matrix B. And I've noticed that the new mateix A looks significantly different depending on the order I arrange the eigenvectors in the transformation matrix. Why does this matter?

For context, the matrices are: $A=\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0\\0&0&0\\0&0&-1\end{bmatrix}$

$B=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\begin{bmatrix}0&1&0\\1&0&1\\0&1&0\end{bmatrix}$

The eigenvalues and vectors are $a_1=0, a_2=1,a_3=-1$

$v_1=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\-1\end{bmatrix}$

$v_2=\frac{1}{2}\begin{bmatrix}1\\\sqrt{2}\\1\end{bmatrix}$

$v_3=\frac{1}{2}\begin{bmatrix}1\\-\sqrt{2}\\1\end{bmatrix}$

Now, I calculate the matrix A in the new basis using formula $A^v=U^\dagger AU$.
Depending on if $U=\begin{bmatrix}v_1&v_2&v_3\end{bmatrix}$ or if $U=\begin{bmatrix}v_3&v_1&v_2\end{bmatrix}$ (the way my prof has in the solutions), I get completely different $A^v$. Could you please explain why the order of the new basis (I thought it is a set?) matters, or point me to some theorem?

Answer (score 1):

The order of a basis **does** matter. Bases are better defined as a "tuple" of vectors than as a set.

One explanation for the effect of switching vectors (in an orthonormal basis) is as follows. In general, we have
$$
\pmatrix{v_1 & v_2 & v_3} \pmatrix{\lambda_1 \\ & \lambda_2 \\ && \lambda_3}\pmatrix{v_1 & v_2 & v_3}^\dagger 
= \lambda_1 v_1 v_1^\dagger
+ \lambda_2 v_2 v_2^\dagger + \lambda_3 v_3 v_3^\dagger.
$$
If the eigenvalues $\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\lambda_3$ are distinct, then it is clear that switching the order of the vectors produces a different sum on the right hand side.

Comment: I don't really see where I permute the eigenvalues in this proceedure? The only thing that matters here, from what I can see and understand, are the eigenvectors.

Comment: @fazan For example, switching the first and second eigenvectors (without also permuting the eigenvalues) leads to the sum $\lambda_1 v_2 v_2^\dagger + \lambda_2 v_1v_1^\dagger + \lambda_3 v_3v_3^\dagger$. If $\lambda_1 \neq \lambda_2$, then this is not the same as the right hand side in my answer. If we also were to **also** switch $\lambda_1,\lambda_2$, we would end up with  $\lambda_2 v_2 v_2^\dagger + \lambda_1 v_1v_1^\dagger + \lambda_3 v_3v_3^\dagger$, which is the same as the right hand side.